# Create a string with an offset

Tags: string, groovy, offset

I would like to create a String where the values have a fixed offset where to add values to a string.
Example

```
ID(0)     Name(10)  Lastname(20)    City(30)
```

example

```
1         Chris     Smith     Paris
```

I have found
StringBuffer.putAt(IntRange range, Object value)
or similiar, but I don't want to have a range, but an index where to start.

StringBufferWriter.write(String text, int offset, int length)

I have found [StrindBufferWriter][1], but not sure if the package codehause is an offical package I can use.

Any suggestions what to use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.padRight` to achieve this effect:

```
def users = [
    [id: 1, name: 'Chris', lastname: 'Smith', city:'Paris'],
    [id: 2, name: 'Tim', lastname: 'Yates', city:'Manchester'],
]

users.each { user ->
    println "${user.id.toString().padRight(10)}${user.name.padRight(10)}${user.lastname.padRight(20)}$user.city"
}
```

Which prints:

```
1         Chris     Smith               Paris
2         Tim       Yates               Manchester
```

Comment: Wow. It is that easy if you know the function :-( I searched and tested  for hours now and testing with the putAt function, but have problem with initialization of the StringBuilder object. Your suggestion is much more elegant. THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!